# How can I hide Contact Form 7 after the user submits? (2022)

Tags: css, wordpress

So this question was asked on the forum around 10 years ago but those methods have been depreciated by the plugin author. I hope someone here can provide an updated solution :)

After the user clicks the “submit” button, the default setting is that the contact form starts over again at step 1 with the default message below it.
[Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayeCh.png)

I only want the default success message to be visible after submission.

What I’ve tried so far:

```
.wpcf7-form.sent p
{
display:none;
}
```

Added the above CSS code to the website CSS (divi page builder), then in the advanced section of the contact form settings. Neither worked.

Would love some help.
Thank you

Comment: It would be nice to have the html code generated. Do you know how to inspect the page ?

Comment: @AlexisVandepitte Yes, you can also visit the page directly here:
fleetwoodfamilylaw.ca/test-form

Comment: @AlexisVandepitte Hi,

Sorry to bug you again.
Are you able to help me?